# Как ограничить количество выводимых элементов yii2 autocomplete?

Tags: yii2

Есть на странице виджет autocomplete

```
<?= $form->field($model,'city')->label(false)->widget(\yii\jui\AutoComplete::className(),[
    'clientOptions' => [
        'source' => ArrayHelper::getColumn(\app\models\City::find()->select('city_name_ru')->all(),'city_name_ru'),
    ],
    'options' => [
        'class' => 'form-control',
        'placeholder' => 'Город',
        'value' => $city
    ]
])?>
```

Как мне ограничить количество выводимых результатов?

Answer (score 2):

Возможно, вам поможет `limit()`. Например:

```
\app\models\City::find()->select('city_name_ru')->limit(100)->all();
```

Answer (score -1):

Решил проблему добавлениям этого параметра

```
'clientOptions' => [
    'minLength' => 3
 ]
```